# Attribute Authorize always return false c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I would like to protect my endpoint through attribute Authorize. But he always return me to login page notwithstanding SignInManager return true
this is my code
`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataBase>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer("Database string");
});


builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cookie =>
{
    cookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    cookie.LoginPath = "/Login/Login";
    cookie.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logout";
    cookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
});


builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
        options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataBase>().AddRoles<Role>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`

`

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

`

Method logining
`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(User.LoginUserModel userModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Register(ModelState.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
            .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList());
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userModel.Email, userModel.Password, true, false);
    if(!result.Succeeded)
        return Login( new List<string>{ "User with this password and login does not exists" });
    return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
}
```

`

I expect the Authorize attribute to work

Comment: Do you make the API calls from within the same browser instance where the user was logged in?

Comment: @NineBerryIn general, my application is not an api, but yes. Requests come from the same browser

Comment: `app.UseAuthentication();` must be before `app.UseAuthorization();`. Your code has it the other way around.

Comment: @pfx Thank You. This really solved the problem. And can you explain / give an article where they will explain why this is so

Comment: In correct middleware order causing the issue. I hope following [correct order as explainded here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services) would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the calls to `app.UseAuthorization();` and `app.UseAuthentication();` in the opposite order than expected.

From the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity)

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

> `UseRouting`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must be called in the order shown in the preceding code.

As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication)

> Authentication is the process of determining a user's identity.
> Authorization is the process of determining whether a user has access to a resource.

You first need to know who the user is, in order to determine what that user is allowed to do.